# How to add xUnit reference to project file?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I'm using Vim and Omnisharp for C# development. I installed xunit into the packages directory.  It's easy to set up the references for Nunit:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.2.6.3\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But I have no idea how to setup the references for xunit.

Comment: You have example for nunit. Do the same for xunit. take whatever path for xunit u have and add reference to your proj file

Comment: But xunit contains just a nupkg file and the portable-xamarin dir from core just contains a props file.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit also comes as a nupkg file, so you did something to install that into your project.  The same should apply to xunit.

But, anyway, you can do this from the command line:

If you don't have nuget installed, you can install nuget itself from https://nuget.org/nuget.exe

Then open a command line prompt, and go to your project, and down to your packages folder.  I assume you already have that since you have NUnit installed.

Run the command:

```
nuget install xunit
```

Answer (score 0):

I used visual studio and installed xunit to my project and here what was added to proj file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\xunit.core.2.0.0\build\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xunit.core.2.0.0\build\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.props')" />

<Reference Include="xunit.abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.abstractions.2.0.0\lib\net35\xunit.abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="xunit.core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.extensibility.core.2.0.0\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>


<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\xunit.core.2.0.0\build\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\xunit.core.2.0.0\build\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.props'))" />
  </Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I stil get 'The type or namespace name `xUnit' could not be found"